# What does the "$+$" typically denote when summing random variables?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two random variables.

When in the literature (for example, in the context of the law of large numbers) one sees statements along the lines of

$$
X = X_1 + X_2
$$

...does the "$+$" simply denote normal function addition, as in

$$
X(k) = X_1(k) + X_2(k)
$$

for all $k$ the domain of $X$, $X_1$, and $X_2$?  Or does this $+$ denote something else?

Comment: If they have values in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then yes, that's most likely what $+$ means.

Comment: It is indeed just adding the functions pointwise: $(X_1 + X_2)(k) = X_1(k) + X_2(k)$.

Comment: I think the comments and answers are correct, but sometime in the literature, $X = X_1+X_2$ means that $X$ has the *distribution* of the sum of the RHS (for example, in the context of CLT). If we view the $X$ as functions, then this really doesn't make sense, but its commonly used). In that case, it's more difficult to pin down what the symbol "+" is referring to...if the summands are iid, then "+" can be taken as "convolution of the probability measures"

Comment: For example, for SLLN, the point-wise behavior of $X$ is critical. However, in WLLN, its really the limiting distribution of the mean of the sequence that is important.

Comment: @Bey: in the context of the law of large numbers, does $+$ denote convulation as opposed to normal addition?

Comment: @Bey The fact that random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution is usually written as $X \sim Y$, not $X=Y$.

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic I agree with you that $X\sim Y$ is correct, but in applied literature I've seen informal use of "=" to imply "equality in distribution"...its not correct, but it has been used.

Comment: @user1770201 in context of LLN, it's the as the others have written here. I'm sorry to have muddied things, my comments probably only apply to things like class notes, presentations, or other informal literature

Comment: @Bey : if $X_1,X_2$ are two random variables then $(X_1,X_2)$ is a random variable and $X_1+X_2$ is a random variable too, whose pdf  is $f_{X_1+X_2}(a)  = \int_{\Omega} P(X_1 = x_1, X_2=a-x_1) d x_1$ (and yes it is not easy to define it rigorously in the general case). I don't even see what it can be if it is not that..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely understand your frustration with the ambiguous and inconsistent notation often used in statistics, even in reputable sources. It is one of the main reasons why I keep having trouble studying it, because I can't help but constantly ask questions like: "Almost surely with respect to what measure? What kind of convergence is implied?..." and the answers are in my opinion not always obvious from the context. Mathematical statisticians, please get it together.

That being out of the way: remember that random variables are essentially just measurable functions $(\Omega, \mathcal{M}, \mathcal{P}) \to (\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{R}^{\otimes n})$ where $(\Omega, \mathcal{M}, \mathcal{P})$ is some probabiilty space, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{R}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. If you have two functions $X_1, X_2 : (\Omega, \mathcal{M}, \mathcal{P}) \to (\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{R}^{\otimes n})$ (same probability space and same $n \in \mathbb{N}$) then one can use them to define new random variables just by using pointwise operations, e.g.
$$
X_1 + X_2 : (\Omega, \mathcal{M}, \mathcal{P}) \to (\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{R}^{\otimes n}) : x \mapsto X_1(x) + X_2(x)
$$
I believe that this is by far the most common interpretation of $X_1 + X_2$. One can show that this function is still measurable. In fact, since every continuous function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is measurable and since compositions of measurable functions are again measurable, every continuous function $f$ in $(x_1, x_2)$ will define a new random variable
$$
f(X_1, X_2) : (\Omega, \mathcal{M}, \mathcal{P}) \to (\mathbb{R}^m, \mathcal{R}^{\otimes m}) : x \mapsto f(X_1(x), X_2(x)).
$$
The case $f(x_1, x_2) = x_1 + x_2$ covers your problem. The distribution $\mathcal{P}_{f(X_1, X_2)}$ of $f(X_1, X_2)$ is always defined: for any set $A \in \mathcal{R}^{\otimes m}$ we have
$$
(\mathcal{P}_{f(X_1, X_2)})(A) = \mathcal{P}(\lbrace x \in \Omega \vert f(X_1(x), X_2(x)) \in A \rbrace)
$$
but it might not be trivial to find a pdf, as was mentioned in user1952009's comment.

The ambiguity you talk about is often not in the "$+$" sign, but in the "$=$" sign. Indeed, it is sometimes used to denote "has the same distribution as". Two stochastic variables $X_1, X_2: (\Omega, \mathcal{M}, \mathcal{P}) \to (\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{R}^{\otimes n})$ are said to have the same distribution if for every $A \in \mathcal{R}^{\otimes n}$
$$
(\mathcal{P}_{X_1})(A) = (\mathcal{P}_{X_2})(A)
$$
where, as before, we define
$$
(\mathcal{P}_{X})(A) = \mathcal{P}(\lbrace x \in \Omega \vert X_1(x) \in A \rbrace)$$
Obviously if two variables are equal, then they have the same distribution, but certainly not the other way around. See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24938/can-two-random-variables-have-the-same-distribution-yet-be-almost-surely-differ) for some examples on this phenomenon.

Comment: Wonderful answer. What exactly is meant by "has the same distribution as"?

Comment: I added it to my answer.

Comment: @Bib-list: Along similar lines, do you know what people mean when they say things like $X_1 = 1$ where $X_1$ is a random variable? It have been burned before by assuming this means that $X_1$ is the constant function that returns all values to $1$.

Comment: Without context, I'd also assume that. Perhaps it means that $1$ is the *outcome* of one specific experiment? For example: suppose $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ is a random sample of some probability distribution and we want to estimate its expected value. If the outcome of an experiment is $(1, 2, 2)$ (informally, in some books, $(X_1, X_2, X_3) = (1, 2, 2)$), then a reasonable estimate for the expected value of the distribution would be $\frac{1 + 2 + 2}{3} \approx 1.67$. If this does not apply to your problem, then I need more context. In that case, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $X_{1}:\Omega\to [0,1]$ and $X=X_1+X_2$ means, for each $\omega\in \Omega$, that $X(\omega)$ is the value of $X_1(\omega)+X_2(\omega)$. Note that is well defined, because are real numbers.

Comment: of course no $ {}{}$  I don't even understand what you mean..

Comment: @user1952009 we are all discussing the random variable $X$ as a function defined on the sample space....if you aren't familiar with that concept, this will likely look confusing.

Comment: I'm familiar with the probability measure concept ! it is not the same as the concept of random variables ! and you can't add two probability measures (you can add two measures, but they you won't get $\mu(\Omega) = 1$)

Comment: @user1952009 Random variable $X$ defined on probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ and with values from some measurable space $(T,\mathcal G)$ is $(\mathcal F,\mathcal G)$-measurable function $X: \Omega \to T$. See, for example, [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Measure-theoretic_definition).

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic : ok I got your notation. it is completely dumb. it is so dumb that we are having this discussion